# Using ubuntu14.04/windows 10 as OS's... my ethernet connection (straight into the wall, not a router) has stopped working

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, ethernet

Window's performed an automatic update without my consent and after restarting to use ubuntu my ethernet stopped working. I've tried several cables and ethernet points. No luck. Please please help!

please note:

ifconfig returns:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2959 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2959 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:398739 (398.7 KB)  TX bytes:398739 (398.7 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:5e:0f:5d:b2:9a  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your ethernet work under Windows? Is it activated there?
I've had it happen before, that if I deactivated my network adapter under Ubuntu/Windows that it was also deactivated in the other OS and I could only reactivate in which ever OS i deactivated it.

Not sure if that helps, but it might be worth trying out.